# React Native AsyncStorage and spread operator is not working

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to save data. However, it's working perfectly while I'm debuging, but when I released my app, I noticed that my app crashed when I saved my data. It seems like the problem is my spread operator. I've tried different ways, but it's still gave me issues. I've been working on this for a couple of days, but no luck. Is there a way to code it.

```
  AsyncStorage.getItem("savedIds", (err, result) => {
            if (result !== null) {
              var newIds = JSON.parse(result);
              var data = [];
              data = [...newIds];
              data.push(obj);
              AsyncStorage.setItem("savedIds", JSON.stringify(data));
            } else {
              AsyncStorage.setItem("savedIds", JSON.stringify(obj));
            }
          });
```

Comment: You are spreading object inside array. It won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I figured it out. I used Array.from(someString)

[This post saved me. It looks like there is another way to solve if you read the post](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21734)

Below is the fixed code

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem("savedIds", (err, result) => {
            if (result !== null) {
              var newIds = JSON.parse(result);
              var data = [];
              data = Array.from(goals);
              data.push(obj);
              AsyncStorage.setItem("savedIds", JSON.stringify(data));
            } else {
              AsyncStorage.setItem("savedIds", JSON.stringify(obj));
            }
          });
```